# css background color of a class not working

Tags: html, css

I have this code in my page :

```css
.0 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">Ma ligne</div>
<div class="0">Ma ligne</div>
<div class="1">Ma ligne</div>
<div class="0">Ma ligne</div>
<div class="1">Ma ligne</div>
<div class="0">Ma ligne</div>
<div class="1">Ma ligne</div>
```

I'd like to set a background color changing if class is 0 or 1. But nothing changes. Am I missing something (obvious) ?

The CSS is loaded, other elements of the page are properly set with CSS style.

Comment: Classes can't start with numbers.

Comment: have a look at the `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` pseudo-selectors.

Comment: @j08691, technically, that is incorrect. As of HTML5, classes (and id's) can start with pretty much anything. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276 ... practically, however, browsers may not be ready for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, identifiers such as class names cannot start with numbers.  Hopefully this will change in the future as browsers move to implement the HTML5 spec fully, but sadly this hasn't happened yet.

These rules are common in most languages, and in this case, CSS.  [Here's a full spec of identifier rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/382456) that are common to languages beyond HTML/CSS.

Replace each class with something like `.b0`, `.b1`, etc, and it will work.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above, this is not correct.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Given that no browsers actually implement this part of the spec, it doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: I think you could have answered the question effectively without making the absolute statement: *Identifiers such as class names cannot start with numbers.*, which is no longer true. As I mentioned in another comment, as of HTML5, `class` values can begin with numbers. However, some browsers may still be adhering to HTML4 rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="zero">Ma ligne</div>

        <div class="first">Ma ligne</div>

        <div class="zero">Ma ligne</div>

        <div class="first">Ma ligne</div>

        <div class="zero">Ma ligne</div>

        <div class="first">Ma ligne</div>
```

and CSS

```
.zero {
    background-color: blue;

}

.first {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare numbers as CSS class. You can however do something like `class="_1"`